# WPF Converter Error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I am new to WPF and i need to use a converter..

I have this in my vb.net code for the converter

```
Namespace converters
<ValueConversion(GetType(Double), GetType(Double))> _
Public Class WidthConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        ' value is the total width available

        Dim otherWidth As Double
        Try
            otherWidth = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter)
        Catch
            otherWidth = 100
        End Try
        If otherWidth < 0 Then
            otherWidth = 0
        End If

        Dim width As Double = CDbl(value) - otherWidth
        If width < 0 Then
            width = 0
        End If
        Return width
        ' columnsCount;
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

End Namespace

In my XAML i have this

```
 <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_NewProject.converters"     
Title="MainWindow" Height="594.796" Width="596.221">
```

Which has no errors but when i do this

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="widthConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I get

> The name "WidthConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WPF_NewProject.converters".

So i need to know if this is a bug or am i doing something wrong?

**Edit**

I have also tried this with the same results.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:converters"
```

**Edit 2**

I just made a new blank project and tried it exactly the same way and it works..?

Comment: try building the project and check it that resolves the error.

Comment: I have tried that, still doesn't work..

Comment: you can first clean the solution the build in these case it helps sometimes..

Comment: Is the converter declared in the same project? Else you will need to specify assembly information too in `xmlns` declaration.

Comment: Yes it is declared in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `The name "WidthConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WPF_NewProject.converters".`

The first line of your converter says `Namespace converters`

Either change your declared namespace to `WPF_NewProject.converters` or change your XML namespace declaration to `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:converters"`